# Bit cli tool is not working after clean install

Tags: bit.dev

bit cli tool is not working after clean installation, i don't understand how do people proceed with bit's tutorials if every command returns the same error: `The system cannot find the path specified.`

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJfLP.png)

What to do to make bit work?

I just followed the installation guide, nothing more
Then I tried to setup any workspace: https://bit.dev/docs/angular-env/use-custom-env

OS: Windows 10
NPM: 9.5.0
Node: v18.15.0

Comment: you can find an answer to this problem in the docs - https://bit.dev/reference/reference/using-bvm#bvm-is-not-recognized-in-your-terminal

Comment: no, there is no such issue in the docs, in my case the cli tool is recognized by windows terminal, I have a feeling the bit reports too vague error for me to handle this, if you look to the picture I posted....